# How to use Docker-compose on Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, docker-compose

I want to use docker-compose on Jenkins. But I faced a problem.
Jenkins showed me that log. How can I solve this problem??

I created docker-compose.yml and I used jenkins/blueocean image. 
Also, I installed docker-compose in Jenkins container.

pipeline {
    agent any

```
environment {
    REGESTRY = 'localhost:5000'        
}

parameters {
    string(name: 'Person', defaultValue: 'Mr Jenkins', description: 'description')
}     

stages {
    stage('Build composeImage'){            
        steps{              
            sh 'ls -al'                               
            sh 'cat docker-compose.yml'
            sh 'docker-compose -v'                
            sh 'docker-compose build'                
        }
    }
    stage('Publish images'){
        steps{
            sh 'docker push $REGESTRY/client'
            sh 'docker push $REGESTRY/server'
        }
    }
}
```

}

- docker-compose build

  ```
  Can't find a suitable configuration file in this directory or any

  parent. Are you in the right directory?



  Supported filenames: docker-compose.yml, docker-compose.yaml
  ```

script returned exit code 1

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure your docker-compose is located in the workspace of Jenkins?

Comment: I'm sure! I used command 'ls' and 'docker-compose -v' for checking successful install

Comment: What does `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml config` shows?

Comment: @Zak This is my docker-compose.yml file

version: '3'
services:
  app:
    image: localhost:5000/client
    build:
      context: ./client
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    networks:
      - uniRSE
  server:
    image: localhost:5000/server
    build:
      context: ./server
      dockerfile: dockerfile
    ports:
      - 4000:4000
    networks:
      - uniRSE
networks:
  uniRSE:
    driver: bridge